# Symfony 2 complex security provider

Tags: php, security, authentication, symfony

I've been hanging around with Symfony 2 for a while, and I have a question on making a custom complex security system.

I need to make a seciruty system that is based on `Module` and `Action` basis, rather then `USER_ROLE`. I will have many modules in the project, and any user should be able to be granted rights for, let's say, read and/or write permissions for any module.

The current S2 Security system does not make any sence in this scenario and I found no similar  issue anywhere on the internet.

Thank you in advance,
Boyan.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using [Access Control Lists (ACLs)](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) to make access decisions on your resources.

Comment: For the separate resources, that's right. I can make a very flexible multi-tier access controll system, but what happens for general restriction to a given module? In a CMS with pages for Articles and Statistics(without any Model object inside), how can I restrict access to different zones in general? For any non-object sections where neither class nor object exists, what can I use? And how a SU can enter and add a given user any rights to a resource or general section at all. 10x